# Why case pattern matching anonymous functions can have two signatures, and have magical call-site compatibility

Tags: scala

In Scala, the pattern matching anonymous function keeps surprising me. I just discovered the following behaviors, and I wanna know how to understand it.

It seems, the parameter signature of the anonymous function `{ case (a, b) => (b, a) }` can be annotated both as a single tuple parameter and a tuple of parameters:

```scala
scala> ({ case (a, b) => (b, a) }: ((Int, Int)) => (Int, Int))
val res1: ((Int, Int)) => (Int, Int) = $Lambda$1160/0x0000000801127040@689fe2a3

scala> ({ case (a, b) => (b, a) }: (Int, Int) => (Int, Int))
val res2: (Int, Int) => (Int, Int) = $Lambda$1161/0x000000080106e840@1784d711
```

Notice `res1` has a tuple parameter, while `res2` has two parameters. Why is that? Is this behavior defined in language specs? (Sorry didn't check out yet, it seems too dense for me at the moment.)

Also, the `res1` function magically accepts both a tuple argument and two arguments at call-site.

```scala
scala> res1((1,2))
val res3: (Int, Int) = (2,1)

scala> res1(1,2)
val res4: (Int, Int) = (2,1)
```

In comparison, `res2` won't accept a tuple argment:

```scala
scala> res2((1,2))
           ^
       error: not enough arguments for method apply: (v1: Int, v2: Int): (Int, Int) in trait Function2.
       Unspecified value parameter v2.
```

What's going on here? Why `res1` can change its signature as it sees fit?

Comment: Which version are you talking about? Unifying tuples and argument lists has been a goal for a very long time, but is very hard to do without massively breaking overload resolution. However, many tiny steps have been done over the last 20 years.

Comment: You have already got answers about why you can call `res1` without creating a tuple. But you haven't got an answer of why `res2` works. Basically the compiler expands your function like `(x, y) => (x, y) match { case (x, y) => your_body }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this behaviour defined in language specs?

It does not seem to be specified according to open issue [Spec doesn't mention automatic tupling #3583](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/3583)

> What's going on here? Why `res1` can change its signature as it sees fit?

This feature is called auto-tupling. It might make some call-sites more natural as discussed in [Remove Two Warts: Auto-Tupling and Multi-Parameter Infix Operations #4311](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/4311)

```
(x, y) == z
z == ((x, y))    // !yuck
```

Many argue for its removal/restriction, for example, [Let’s drop auto-tupling](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/lets-drop-auto-tupling/1799).

Compiler flag [`-Xlint:adapted-args`](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11110#issuecomment-615376000) can warn when auto tupling happens, for example

```
➜  ~ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.3 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_265).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> def foo (x: (Int, Int)) = x
def foo(x: (Int, Int)): (Int, Int)

scala> foo (1,2)
val res0: (Int, Int) = (1,2)

scala> :replay -Xlint:adapted-args
replay> def foo (x: (Int, Int)) = x
def foo(x: (Int, Int)): (Int, Int)

replay> foo (1,2)
        foo (1,2)
            ^
On line 2: warning: adapted the argument list to the expected 2-tuple: add additional parens instead
                signature: foo(x: (Int, Int)): (Int, Int)
          given arguments: 1, 2
         after adaptation: foo((1, 2): (Int, Int))
def foo(x: (Int, Int)): (Int, Int)
val res0: (Int, Int) = (1,2)
```

Another related flag is [`-Xlint:multiarg-infix`](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8951), for example

```
➜  ~ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.3 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_265).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> def % (a: Int, b: Int) = (a,b)
def $percent(a: Int, b: Int): (Int, Int)

scala> :replay -Xlint:multiarg-infix
replay> def % (a: Int, b: Int) = (a,b)
            ^
        warning: multiarg infix syntax looks like a tuple and will be deprecated
def $percent(a: Int, b: Int): (Int, Int)
```

Comment: @user `res1(1,2)` works because of auto tupling otherwise we would have to write `res((1,2))`

Answer (score 4):

Scala will automatically convert an argument list to a tuple if required:

```
def f(arg: (Int, Int)) = ???

f(1, 2) // OK
```

It will not do the reverse conversion

```
def g(a: Int, b: Int) = ???

g((1, 2)) // Error "not enough arguments for method"
```

Needless to say there is some debate over this feature...

Answer (score 2):

The other two answers are right that auto-tupling lets you pass in 2 arguments as if they were a tuple to `res1`, but they don't explain why `res1` and `res2` can have different types when they were created with the same function literal.

One nice thing about using pattern matching functions is that even when your function accepts multiple arguments, you can treat them as a single tuple and pattern match on that. (See [Pattern Matching Anonymous Functions](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions)). Your type annotation tells the compiler that `res2` has 2 `Int` parameters, so it basically turns your function literal into this (it tuples the arguments before pattern matching on them):

```
(arg1, arg2) => (arg1, arg2) match {
  case (a, b) => (b, a)
}
```

Whereas `res1` is kept basically the same, since it accepts a single tuple input anyways:

```
tuple => tuple match {
  case (a, b) => (b, a)
}
```